# Ruby - parsing JSON coming via URL

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, url

I'm sending a JSON object to ruby with javascript. But I cannot parse it in there. I tried following stuff but no luck. Also I've been searching around for while now, but I couldn't find anything  helpful.

Note that I'm very new ruby.

My trials:

```
def initialize(game_conf_json)        
    parsed_conf = JSON.parse(conf_json)
    @param1 = parsed_conf['name'][0]
    @param2 = parsed_conf['surname'][0]

    =begin
    I also tried this:
    @param1 = parsed_conf['name']
    @param2 = parsed_conf['surname']

    But no matter what other things I try, I'm getting the following error:
    "21:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)"

    OR

    "can't convert Array into String (TypeError), "

    =end


    File.open("some_direc/conf.json", "w") do |f|
        f.write(game_conf_json)
    end

end
```

I create the json in javascript like this:

```
var json_of_form_vars = {};
json_of_form_vars.name = name_val;
json_of_form_vars.surname = surname_val;
```

And send it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../fundament/dispatch.rb/",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "conf="+json_of_form_vars,
    .....
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there any proper tutorial for this of problem?

**UPDATE1 (After suggestions):**
I used JSON.stringify and then passed the object to ruby. And then I finally able to print the object in ruby. It's listed below:

```
{"name": "METIN", "surname": "EMENULLAHI"}
```

The method .class claims that it is an array. But I cannot access data with classical ways, like:

```
array['name']
```

the error is:

> can't convert String into Integer

And when I try to pass it to the `JSON.parse` in ruby, it gives me the following error:

> can't convert Array into String

So I used `JSON.parse(conf_array.to_json)`, but again when accessing the data it gives the same error like arrays:

> can't convert String into Integer

What should be done now?

**UPDATE2**
Here is my cgi handler which passes the URL parameters to appropriate places:

```
cgi_req = CGI::new
puts cgi_req.header

params_from_request = cgi_req.params

logger.error "#{params_from_request}"

action_todo = params_from_request['action'][0].chomp

base = Base.new

if action_todo.eql?('create')
    conf_json = params_from_request['conf']
    # This line prints the json like this: {"name": "SOME_NAME", "surname": "SOME_SURNAME"}
    logger.error "#{conf_json}"
    base.create_ident(conf_json) 
end
```

And in Base class:

```
def create_ident(conf_json)
   require 'src/IdentityCreation'
   iden_create = IdentityCreation.new(conf_json)
end
```

`IdentityCreation`'s constructor is listed above.

**UPDATE3:**

Ok, I now get at least something out of the array. But when I access a key, it displays the key itself:

```
parsed_conf = JSON.parse(conf_json.to_json)
@param1 = parsed_conf[0]['name']
@param2 = parsed_conf[0]['surname']

# At this point when I print the @param1, it gives me "name"(the key), not "SOME_NAME"(the value).
```

Comment: You'll have to include a sample of the `JSON` you're trying to parse.

Comment: Your post data looks suspicious to me - a mixture of form encoded parameters and json data. When you do `"conf=" + json_of_form_vars` it's going to try and convert that javascript object to a string, which will likely yield something unhelpful like [Object object]. You need to use JSON.stringify to convert it to json.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, you should post that as an answer. That's what the OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @AlexD yup, me being lazy!

Comment: I tried your suggestions and updated my question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are doing in your controller. Perhaps you could elaborate on that

Comment: I don't do anything in the controller. As soon as I got the object from the JS, I pass it to my class's constructor, which I posted in my question. After that point, the only stuff I'm doing is in that constructor. there's nothing else. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it  finally. Using all the suggestions made under this post and also my irb experiences with hashes, arrays, json and etc.

So instead of converting my object (`conf_json`) to json (with `to_json`), I passed it to `JSON.parse` as a string like below:

```
parsed_conf = JSON.parse(%{#{conf_json}})
```

It seems kind of weird to me, because when try to pass it to function like below, I got the error of `can't convert Array into String`.

```
parsed_conf = JSON.parse(conf_json)
```

But it is working like a charm right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of parsing a JSON string. If you still have problems, publish the generated JSON so that we can try it.

```
require 'json'
require 'ap'

string = %{
  {"configurations" : [ 
  { "drinks" : [
          {"menus" : [
            { "hot" : [
              {"id":15,"unit":"0.33", "price":"1", "currency":"Euro", "position": 4},
              {"id":15,"unit":"0.33", "price":"1", "currency":"Euro", "position": 6}
            ] },

            { "cold" : [
          {"id":15,"unit":"0.33", "price":"1", "currency":"Euro", "position": 4},
              {"id":15,"unit":"0.33", "price":"1", "currency":"Euro", "position": 6}
             ] },

            { "terminals" : { "id" : 4, "id": 6, "id": 7 } }, 

            { "keys" : { "debit" : "on", "credit": "off" }  }

          ] }
  ] } ] } 
}

hash = JSON.parse(string)
ap hash
```

gives

```
{
    "configurations" => [
        [0] {
            "drinks" => [
                [0] {
                    "menus" => [
                        [0] {
                            "hot" => [
                                [0] {
                                          "id" => 15,
                                        "unit" => "0.33",
                                       "price" => "1",
                                    "currency" => "Euro",
                                    "position" => 4
                                },
```

etc..

Comment: When I try to print the JSON string coming from javascript in ruby, it prints only `[Object object]`. And the `.class`, also gives the same output. So how can I dump this string in ruby. Obviously, it is not a plain string. Also I used `pretty print`, but no luck either.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're not actually posting json. You're attemping to post json wrapped inside form encoded parameters. In addition, when you do

```
"conf=" + json_of_form_vars
```

javascript will convert `json_of_form_vars` to a string for you but that conversion isn't the same as dumping to JSON. Javascript default string conversions are pretty useless for objects, so you'll need to use JSON.stringify to get actual json.

Since you're composing the body as a string literal you'll also need to escape any special characters that aren't allowed (or have special meaning) in this context. It's usually easier to let jquery do the heavy lifting, with something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../fundament/dispatch.rb/",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {conf: JSON.stringify(json_of_form_vars)}
```